# Manipulating linked lists in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures

I'm trying to write a code to manipulate a linked list, here's what I have so far:

```
def main ():
    readFile('list1.txt')
    head1 = readFile('list1.txt') 
    profile1 = head1
    readFile('list2.txt')
    head2 = readFile('list2.txt')
    profile2 = head2
    choice(profile1, profile2)



def choice(profile1, profile2):
    print("  ")
    print("Welcome to your Netflix list!")
    print("  ")
    print("Type 'one' to view profile #1's custom list")
    print("Type 'two' to view profile #2's custom list")
    print("type 'merge' to merge the two profile lists")
    print("Type 'check' to delete duplicate values in your merged list")
    print("Type 'add' to add values to your (profile #1's) list")
    print("Type 'delete' to delete a value from your (profile #1's) list")
    print("  ")
    choice = input("Please input your choice: ").lower()
    if (choice == 'one'):
        display(profile1, profile1, profile2)
    elif (choice == 'two'):
        display(profile2, profile1, profile2)
    elif (choice == 'merge'):
        merge(profile1, profile2)
    elif(choice == 'check'):
        check(profile1, profile2)
    elif (choice == 'add'):
        add(profile1, profile2)
    elif(choice == 'delete'):
        delete(profile1)
    else:
        print("That input was not understood. Try typing that again")
        choice(profile1, profile2)

def add(profile1, profile2):
    insert = print(input("Type the name you would like to add: "))
    addToEnd(profile1, insert)
    choice(profile1, profile2)


def merge(profile1, profile2):
    head = profile1
    ptr = head
    while ptr != None:
        print(ptr['data'])
        ptr = ptr['next']
    choice = print(input("Input number before which to insert the list: "))
    ptr = head
    while ptr['next'] != choice:
        ptr = ptr['next']
    nodeAfter = ptr['next']
    profile2['next'] = nodeAfter
    ptr['next']= profile2
    head = profile1
    ptr = head
    while ptr != None:
        print(ptr['data'])
        ptr = ptr['next']


def display(profile, profile1, profile2):
    head = profile
    ptr = head
    while ptr != None:
        print(ptr['data'])
        ptr = ptr['next']
    choice(profile1, profile2)



def readFile (file):
    with open(file, 'r') as ins:
        profile = {}
        profile['data'] = ins.readline().strip()
        profile['next'] = None
        head = profile
        for line in ins:
            addToEnd(head, line)
        return profile   


def addToEnd (head, value):
    newEntry = {}
    newEntry['data'] = value.strip()
    newEntry['next'] = None
    ptr = head
    while ptr['next'] != None:
        ptr = ptr['next']
    ptr['next'] = newEntry
    return ptr


main()
```

It's obviously supposed to do more things than I've put, but I can't get past these ones. When I try and use the 'add' function, it remembers that there is a link, but it only says 'none' so whatever is typed in is lost. 
Likewise in the merge function, it doesn't do it, which I'm guessing is because the links/values have no numbers, so it doesn't know where to insert or something like that. Is it at all possible to give values/links in a linked list a number? I'm also getting a lot of errors in passing the heads to the other functions so it can return to the menu once the other function is done. I really have no idea what's going wrong, and I feel like it might be a fundamental thing about linked lists I'm missing.

Edit: I realize using a linked list makes no sense in python. But this is my homework, so unfortunately this is what I must do.

Comment: https://tekku.xyz/data/xengallery/0/1-7afb11957cdeb69ec574438adb29cbd5.jpg?1451135848

Comment: in Python, you dont need linked lists. You can just use ordinary lists...

Comment: @ssm Linked lists make perfect sense in Python, as much as they do in any other language.  Just because Python (surprisingly) calls arrays lists doesn't magically mean linked lists aren't useful.  Python just doesn't provide any direct support for them.

Comment: One thing that I noticed is that your addToEnd returns the last node that you inserted, maybe that's not the behavior that you want. Should probably return head